# UWP Bad Image Exception

Tags: uwp

I have an issue where, for some reason, I am getting a bad image exception when loading my UWP project. This has started happening recently. Initially the complaint was about the minimum target not being set to something appropriate, but once I fixed that I can't seem to get rid of this new error.

Here's a small snapshot.

[UWP Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxvzT.png)

Here is a screenshot of the packages installed.

[Nuget Package Screenshot Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5qUq.png)

[Nuget Package Screenshot Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmJjH.png)

Comment: Please share which nuget package you have installed ?

Comment: Hey, added 2 screenshots of them ;)

Comment: You should _Manage NuGet for solution_, not project, and focus on the consolidate tab, make sure all projects referenced for the test use the same version of DI